# Typo3 TCA override tt_content add palette to existing tab (--div--)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I try to add a palette to the tt_content table under the existing tab 'General'.
Here my tt_conten.php file.

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

// Feld definieren
$tempColumns = [
 'tx_imagetext_color' => [
 'label' => 'color',
 'exclude' => 0,
 'config' => [
 'type' => 'input',
 'eval' => 'trim',
 ]
 ],
 'tx_imagetext_image' => [
 'label' => 'image',
    'config' => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
    'special' => 'languages',
    'items' => [
        [
        'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
        -1,
        'flags-multiple'
        ]
    ],
    'default' => 0,
    ],
 ]
];

// Feld der allgemeinen Datensatzbeschreibung hinzufügen - noch keine Ausgabe im Backend!
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', $tempColumns);

// Feld einer neuen Palette hinzufügen
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
        'tt_content',
        'imagetext',
        'tx_imagetext_color, tx_imagetext_image'
        );

// Neue Palette dem Tag hinzufügen, nach dem Titel - Dadurch Anzeige im Backend
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
 'tt_content',
 '--div--;general,
 --palette--;;imagetext',
 '',
 ''
);
```

Typo3 creates a new general on the end with the right palette.
But I want that the palette should appear in the already existing tab General.

How can I achive that?

Comment: I tried sth like this: addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'general', '<your-palette>','after:bodytext')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--div--;general` explicitly creates a new tab with the name "general".

If you only want your new palette to appear right after some other field in the "general" tab you only need to specify that field as the last argument of addToAllTCAtype function. As you wrote "nach dem Titel" I assume you want it appear right after the header field. The following works for me in TYPO3 10 but I think it should be the same in v. 9.5.xx

```
// Neue Palette hinzufügen, nach dem Titel - Dadurch Anzeige im Backend
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    '--palette--;;imagetext',
    '',
    'after:header'
);
```

A little more explanation

`addToAllTCAtypes` takes four arguments:

1. argument: Table to add the field for
2. argument: New field (or in you case palette)
3. argument: List of types to add this field to (in your case
   empty, as you want the field to appear in all types, I assume)
4. argument: Position where to add the field. Can either be "before:fieldname", "after:fieldname" or "replace:fieldname")

Comment: thanks that works fine. I had some addional questions: I was thinking, if I put a name after --palette-- this would as palette headline, but nothing is showing up. Is it also possible to add this palette only if my extension is selected?

Comment: If the solution worked for you, would you mind marking it as accepted answer?
As for you additional question:
Adding a name for the palette inbetween the two ;; in your palette inclusion should normally work, yes. `--palette--;Your Palette Name here;imagetext'`.
As to your second question, what do you mean by "if my extension is selected"? You mean if the user is trying to insert an element of an CType added by your extension?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I see the pallette all the time, if I open a new content in a page. But it would be only necessary, to see the palette, if the associated plugin is used. Is this possible$

Comment: As third argument in addToAllTCAtypes you can optionally define the content types this palette should be show in, e.g. 'textmedia' or serveral type in a comma-separeted list .eg. 'textmedia,image'.

Comment: The CType for my extension is list and the list_type album_showalbum. What I have to use as the third argument$